# Need regex to filter out .ru and other spammy email address

Tags: php, regex

I already am using php's `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` to find out if the address is valid email.

I'm just gonna go ahead and block .ru email addresses.  What regex and code should I use?  Any other spammy tlds or addresses that you block would be appreciated as well.

I have tried this, but want to be sure I'm catching it correctly and catch other spammy emails.

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle){
    $length = strlen($needle);
    return (substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle);
}
```

Thanks VG:

```
function russianEmail($email,$endings = array('\.ru')){
    return (preg_match('/('.implode('|', $endings).')$/i', $email))?true:false;
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Edited.  I have used, successfully, the function above, but it is not regex.  I'm not saying that's a bad thing only that it might not be the best thing.

Comment: The regex for an email address ending in .ru is trivial: `/\.ru$/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match multiple domain zones (or just endings) with following code:

```
$endings = array('\.ru'); // you can add zones here
preg_match('/('.implode('|', $endings).')$/i', $email);
```

This regex is also case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use (not all my own work however):
Replace the link to russianbrides.com with whatever dark place you want to send the spammer.

```
function my_inArray($needle, $haystack) {
//  this function allows wildcards in the array to be searched
    foreach ($haystack as $value) {
    if (true === fnmatch($value, $needle)) {
    return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

//  Blocking Wildcard Emails.

```
$deny = array(
"*@hotmobilephoneoffers.com",
"*@*.ru",
"*@*.su",
);

if (my_inarray (strtolower($email_from), $deny)) {
    header("location: http://www.russianbrides.com/");
    exit();
}
```